# Number of arguments specified by template

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17

I have a class that needs to adapt the number of arguments a member `std::function` takes depending on the classes template parameters. The parameters are declared like so:

```
template<char Id, char ... Ids>
class term;
```

Then in the body of the class I have a `std::function` that needs to take `1 + sizeof...(Ids)` arguments of some numeric type (all of the same type).

The body is declared like so:

```
template<char Id, char ... Ids>
class term{
    public:
        template<typename ... Args>
        void operator()(Args &&... args){
            fn(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }

        std::function<void(/* whats do? */)> fn;
};
```

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't stated what the parameter types are for `fn`, I'll assume all `char`. In that case:

```
std::function<void(char, decltype(Ids)...)> fn;
```

You can adjust this to make the parameters different types, but how you adjust it can depend on what the signature should look like exactly.

For all the same numeric type, the easiest adjustment is probably this:

```
std::function<void(char, decltype(Ids, YourNumericType{})...)> fn;
```

Comment: I wouldn't have a asked a question for that haha I'll update the question

Comment: @CoffeeandCode, Updated.

Comment: While you're at it, how would I do the same thing but for function parameters?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode, I don't understand the question. It's probably worth asking as a separate question if the same answer doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach would be using an alias template, as an example:

```
template<char...>
using Arg = int; // or whatever is your type

// ...

std::function<void(Arg<>, Arg<Ids>...)> fn;
```

Or even:

```
template<char>
using Arg = int; // or whatever is your type

// ...

std::function<void(Arg<Id>, Arg<Ids>...)> fn;
```

It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<functional>
#include<cassert>

template<char...>
using Arg = int;

template<char Id, char ... Ids>
class Term {
public:
    template<typename ... Args>
    void operator()(Args &&... args){
        fn(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    std::function<void(Arg<>, Arg<Ids>...)> fn;
};

int main() {
    Term<'a', 'b', 'c'> term;
    assert((std::is_same<decltype(term.fn), std::function<void(int, int, int)>>::value));
}
```